# Application to access batch jobs/executions/steps including properties

Tags: wildfly, jberet

While I have some JSR-352 based batch jobs running in Wildfly, from my frontend application I'd like to show/manage some of the batch jobs. While I am able to display the most recent executions and even their steps, I seem to be unable to access the job's or step's properties. Access to them seems only granted through @BatchProperty, which will only work if accessed from within the job.

However my UI sits outside, and I simply see no hint how that can be accomplished. What may I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch API (JSR 352) exposes job and step execution data to a client program, and it does not include batch job and step definition data. The job and step properties are part of the definition data declared in job xml files and thus are not directly exposed. If the client program needs it, you can save them to other part of the application that makes them available to the UI.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the standard is quite poor and should be enhanced. The properties for job and step can be set in the job xml, but then at runtime the values may differ, and custom code in batchlets and chunks may access the context and modify the properties as well. So it may make sense to look at these contexts at runtime from a management interface. But you confirmed that the JSR does not specify such access.

Comment: I have to correct myself: It seems the properties are immutable. So they will not change during runtime of the job.